# I get a NullPointerException when trying the Eclipse "Hello World" tutorial

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, adt

I was finishing up the "Hello World" tutorial in Eclipse (with the ADT plugin) and apparently, you are supposed to rename the string resource "hello" with "Hello Android, I am a string resource". Well, Java.Lang.NullPointerException pops up with four, "An error has occurred. See error log for details." There is nothing in the error log! For every letter I type to rename it, Java.Lang.NullpointerException pops up and I have no clue what is wrong. I don't have any other errors or problems with my code.
Does it have something to do with the "missing" gen file, because I had to change my Java to 1.6 to solve that... Maybe I need an update?

Comment: Post your code that you're having an issue with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same problem.
I found a solution here: http://androidforums.com/developer-101/112731-problems-getting-eclipse-android-installed.html

Just replace your resources tag with the following:

`<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`

Restart Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

The error messages get posted to the LogCat tab.  Look there instead of the Console.  You also should try right clicking on the project, choose <kbd>Android Tools</kbd> → <kbd>Fix Project Properties</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

[Caution:](http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html) There are known issues with the ADT plugin running with Eclipse 3.6. Please stay on 3.5 until further notice.

Probably you have installed latest Eclipse 3.6 Helios. You will need to switch to 
Eclipse 3.5.2 Galileo instead.

Comment: 3.6 with ADT works fine for me. I've been using 3.6 since like RC4

Comment: Thanks, but the problem was solved with a system restart. It happens every once in a while when I click on the resources tab but not often. Thanks anyway!